# Calculating mse for multiple dimensionality reduction technique

Tags: r, pca, autoencoder, tsne

I'm trying to find a metric to compare multiple dimensionality reduction techniques similar to what was done in this blog post [pca-vs-autoencoders-for-dimensionality-reduction](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/07/pca-vs-autoencoders-for-dimensionality-reduction/)...

Specifically this part of the comparison

```
# pCA reconstruction
pca.recon <- function(pca, x, k){
  mu <- matrix(rep(pca$center, nrow(pca$x)), nrow = nrow(pca$x), byrow = T)
  recon <- pca$x[,1:k] %*% t(pca$rotation[,1:k]) + mu
  mse <- mean((recon - x)^2)
  return(list(x = recon, mse = mse))
}

xhat <- rep(NA, 10)
for(k in 1:10){
  xhat[k] <- pca.recon(pca, x_train, k)$mse
}

ae.mse <- rep(NA, 5)
for(k in 1:5){
  modelk <- keras_model_sequential()
  modelk %>%
    layer_dense(units = 6, activation = "tanh", input_shape = ncol(x_train)) %>%
    layer_dense(units = k, activation = "tanh", name = "bottleneck") %>%
    layer_dense(units = 6, activation = "tanh") %>%
    layer_dense(units = ncol(x_train))

  modelk %>% compile(
    loss = "mean_squared_error", 
    optimizer = "adam"
  )

  modelk %>% fit(
    x = x_train, 
    y = x_train, 
    epochs = 5000,
    verbose = 0
  )

  ae.mse[k] <- unname(evaluate(modelk, x_train, x_train))
}

df <- data.frame(k = c(1:10, 1:5), mse = c(xhat, ae.mse), method = c(rep("pca", 10), rep("autoencoder", 5)))
ggplot(df, aes(x = k, y = mse, col = method)) + geom_line()
```

i will like to add other techniques to the mix such as TSNE from Rtsne package, UMAP from the umap package and IVIS from the ivis package (currently not on CRAN but can be installed like so ->

```
devtools::install_github("beringresearch/ivis/R-package")
library(ivis)
install_ivis()
```

The data input and processing for all the techniques are similar but it seems some of them already have mse determination baked into their functions (e.g. autoencoder). I'm wondering if anyone has experience with what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Your code example does not run. Introduce at example dataset. It seems pca object refer to a return from the prcomp function but it is not defined. Prefer to use the generic predict method.

Decomposition(DC) can be seen as lossy compression. To benchmark: Do DC, then reconstruction.  Choose an error function measure the loss of precision from orig. to reconstructed data.

DC can be used as preprocessing for many other methods such as regression/classification/visualisation. To benchmark: Do DC, plug into other method. Evaluate success of this other method given decomposition algorithm.

Comment: @Soren, to make the question easier, i referred to this post ... https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/07/pca-vs-autoencoders-for-dimensionality-reduction/. so the code above is not wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Think of soon this question is not about us. Perhaps 1000 others will look at this as any other question over the next 5 years. They will appreciate it to be minimal and reproducible, anyways the answer should be.

Comment: I failed to give a minimal answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Different decomposition methods can be regarded as interchangeable *gears* in a statistical *machine*, that serves to be useful to you, the creator.

To pick the best gear, the metric you evaluate by should not necessarily concern the gears, but how well the machine performs overall with each gear inserted respectively.

**Disregard the gear specs:**
You have a couple of gears which all come with their own validation specs from their *factories* (packages). Those numbers/summeries/specs are likely not what you want. Likely gears will not be provided with the same metrics, so it is hard to do a fair comparison. Also, those metrics will be all about the gears and not about your specific machine anyways. Do not do as the blog suggest and mix machine metrics with the gears in the `pca.recon()`. Let the gears be gears, and delay the metric evaluation onto the machine level.

**Does the gear fit at all?:** You need to check for your specific machine, that all your candidate gears will actually fit inside. Your gears for your composition/reconstruction machine, must be able to *turn both ways*. [The t-sne is only designed to turn forward and do decomposition, so it is not possible to do a meaningful evaluation.](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/34352/reconstructing-original-data-points-from-t-sne-output) Likewise for the UMAP.   Maybe the whole reconstruction loss benchmarking thing was not the actual machine you wanted to use in the first place. Maybe just a side project to pick gears for another machine...  If your machine is to make beautiful plots then good quantitative benchmarking is hard to come by. If your machine is some initial decomposition mixed with a simple classifier, then the t-sne gear will fit just fine and some prediction accuracy metric is likely useful to pick gears with  .

**Interfacing various gears:** The gears will actually not fit out-of-the-box into your machine because the size and form is not the same. Each gear needs individual adaptation. You may be tempted to re-fit the machine to the gear and that will do for a few gears. That would be to literal copy-paste your machine code, insert and adapt each gear. A more scalable way is to just interface the gears, such you can leave them in a bag next to the machine and let a robot insert one gear at the time and write you a report. That is a main selling point of frameworks such as sklearn, caret and keras. You could also code it your self. Here is a simple example  :

```
rm(list=ls())
#some data
X <- iris[,c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width")]

#my_gear, prcomp wrapped in an interface
#any gear must have the gear(X, N, ...) signature
pca_decompose <- function(X, N=2, ...) {
  
  #implement gear forward (decompose)
  pca <- prcomp(
    X, rank. = N,
    scale = FALSE #must be false, beacuse reconstructor below does not support re-scaling, because I'm lazy.
  )
  
  #implement gear backward (reconstruct)
  reconstruct <- function(Xnew = pca$x) {
    
    # a pca reconstructor implementation similar to function from the blog, pca already in closure
    # I think the blog mistankenly referred to pca$x instead of x sometimes
    pca.recon <- function(x, k){
      x_recon <- x[,1:k] %*% t(pca$rotation[,1:k])
      #slightly more effecient way to reapply center
      for(i in seq_along(pca$center)) x_recon[,i] <- x_recon[,i] + pca$center[i] 
      return(x_recon)
    }
    X_rc <- pca.recon(Xnew, k=N)
    return(X_rc)
  }
  
  #wrap up the interface
  self <- list(
    X_decomposed = pca$x,  # any decomposition must be named X_dc
    reconstruct = reconstruct
  )
  
  class(self) <- c("my_pca","my_universal_gear")
  return(self)
}

#define a machine with the relevant use case
my_machine <- function(gear, data, ...) {
 dc_obj <- gear(data, ...)
 data_rc <- dc_obj$reconstruct(dc_obj$X_decomposed)
}

#define the most useful metric
my_metric <- function(X,Y) {
  # this 'multivariate' mse, is not commonly used I think.
  # but whatever floats the boat
  mean((X-Y)^2) 
}

#define how to evaluate.
#try the gear in the mahine and meassure outcome with metric
my_evaluation <- function(gear, machine, data, metric, ...) {
  data <- as.matrix(data)
  output <- machine(gear,data, ...)
  my_metric(data,output)
}

#useful syntactic sugar
set_params <- function(gear, ...) {
  params = list(...)
  function(...) do.call(gear,c(list(...),params))
}

#evaluate a gear
my_evaluation(
  gear = pca_decompose,
  machine = my_machine,
  data = X,
  #gear params
  N=2
)

#the same as
my_evaluation(
  gear = set_params(pca_decompose,N=2), #nice to preset gear params
  machine = my_machine,
  data = X
)

#define all gears to evaluate
#the gearbag could also in another usecase be a grid search of optimal hyper-parameters
my_gearbag = list(
  pca_dc_N1 = set_params(pca_decompose,N=1),
  pca_dc_N2 = set_params(pca_decompose,N=2),
  pca_dc_N3 = set_params(pca_decompose,N=3),
  pca_dc_N4 = set_params(pca_decompose,N=4)
  #put also autoencoder or what ever in the gearbag
)

my_robot <- function(evaluation, machine, gearbag, data) {
  results <- sapply(
    X = gearbag, #this X is not the data put placeholder for what to iterate
    FUN = evaluation,
    machine = machine,
    data = X
  )
  
  report = list(
    README = "metric results for gears",
    results = results
  )
}


my_report <- my_robot(my_evaluation, my_machine, my_gearbag, data)

print(my_report)
```

**printout**

```
$README
[1] "metric results for gears"

$results
   pca_dc_N1    pca_dc_N2    pca_dc_N3    pca_dc_N4 
8.560431e-02 2.534107e-02 5.919048e-03 1.692109e-31
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond to my question.... i sincerely don't see how this answers my question.

Comment: "Disregard the gear specs", section explains why you likely are looking for metrics the wrong places. "Does the gear fit at all", explains what you want to achieve hardly can be done , because t-sne and umap is not easily reversible. "Interfacing various gears" section is inspiration for how to code up evaluations, metrics and machines in a tidy way for any problem.

Comment: Good luck though :)  Again, your question is not very clear cut, so expect many interpretations thereof. Try check the guidelines: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm simply looking for a metric to compare the amount of information (variability) that will be captured by dimension or components ( using PCA here as an example). I do understand the strength and weakness of each of my method individually, but i need a metric to evaluate their performance. In tidymodels for example, i can easily compare the performance of UMAP and PCA, but i want to extend the comparison to include other algorithms not implemented in tidymodels... i really don't know how.

Comment: "All models are wrong, but some are useful", George Box. I speculate you're stuck, because you do not see the bigger picture. The machine/gear analogy was an attempt to hint you to think about was is useful to YOU. Think of why you're doing this task at all. Then code a candidate machine that serves you well. Now defining useful metrics is easier because you know what you want. Then try to plug in and out subcomponents to see if you can get it to work better. Good luck, I will tap out here.